# A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure Process

Tags: secure-store

I was trying to create the passphrase for the first time for the secure store service application, there was an error on the page and I have this on the event log

Any idea how can I fix this?

```
A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure Process Name: w3wp Process ID: 2392 AppDomain Name: /LM/W3SVC/464399676/ROOT-1-130288845739498176 AppDomain ID: 2 Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:service:8fe3402f85b74e21a46c57ba38cf2e35#authority=urn:uuid:6089ed584c0746c088a9444ef5588bd3&authority=https://mycentraladminserver:32844/Topology/topology.svc Active Endpoints: 3 Failed Endpoints:1 Affected Endpoint: https://mycentraladminserver:32844/8fe3402f85b74e21a46c57ba38cf2e35/SecureStoreService.svc/https
```

Comment: Very interesting question! Did you follow the guidelines (and video) in the technet article [Configure the Secure Store Service in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806866.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one of the services are not running!

> To start the Secure Store Service
>   1.On the Central Administration home page, in the System Settings section, click Manage services on server.
>
> 2.Above the Service list, click the Server drop-down list, and then click Change Server.
>
> 3.Select the application server where you want to run the Secure Store Service.
>
> 4.In the Service list, click Start next to Secure Store Service.

above taken from the link Benny supplied!

if that doesnt work also make sure:

make sure that claims service is running as it uses claims:

Claims to windows token services

Comment: The Claims to Windows token service was stopped, thanks a lot

Comment: no probs happy to help!